# Does one need to tag all "no longer needed" comments or are moderators going through the list after seeing one?

Tags: support, comments, flagging, etiquette

There are situations where, after a short discussion in comments, a post is edited to reflect the outcome of the discussions. In these cases, I would like the no-longer needed comments to be removed.

Is it enough to flag the first one?, i.e., will moderators systematically go through the other comments to see which need removal? Or is it better to tag all comments individually? (I am concerned to over-burden the moderators when tagging all comments - not sure if it creates more work for them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever helps us clearly identify which comments need  to be removed and why  is best. Otherwise we have to read the whole post, understand what the substance of the suggestion in the comment was, and compare to how the edits affected the question and the suggestion. That can get very complicated very fast with multiple commenters, suggestions, and edits on the same post.

Flagging all of the relevant comments is usually fine. If it's just a few and it's pretty clear what happened then flagging the first one should do the trick and we'll figure it out. If it's a complicated situation, the best is really to flag most of them with the relevant generic flag, and flag a particular one or the whole post with a custom flag explaining clearly what needs to be removed and why to help bring us up to speed with what's going on.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @mblo no problem. Thank you for being considerate of our workload

Comment: While I agree with this answer, I'll add that (IMO), if all the comments are no longer needed, and the reason they're not isn't highly individual-comment-dependent, then it's probably clearest to flag the post with a custom flag indicating as much.

Comment: In other words (continuing my previous comment), when you say "If it's just a few and it's pretty clear what happened then flagging the first one should do the trick and we'll figure it out.", I say flagging the post is probably clearer.